# Socket not visible using Python on Ubuntu Server

Tags: python, sockets, ubuntu

I'm writing an application that is supposed to listen for a client, and when it connects, it should grab some data. It works fine when I run it locally on either my own computer, or the server, but when I try and run it on the server, and connect from my computer, it doesn't work at all. The connection times out.

I've tried running the program, and then checking netstat (on the server), and it only shows anything if I have my host set to localhost. If I set my host to the server's IP address (or hostname, or `socket.getfqdn()`), then nothing shows up in netstat.

The code is as follows:

```
class Listen(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.PORT = 2079
        self.HOST = socket.getfqdn()
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.finished = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self.finished.set()
        self.join()

    def run(self):
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.bind((self.HOST, self.PORT))
        server.listen(5)
        while not self.finished.isSet():
            try:
                server.settimeout(1)
                channel, details = server.accept()
                server.settimeout(None)
                Client(channel, details).start()
            except socket.timeout:
                pass

class Client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, channel, details):
        self.channel = channel
        self.details = details
        self.log = []
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print 'Received connection:', self.details [ 0 ]
        entries = int(self.channel.recv(3))
        print "Receiving", entries, "new entries"

        for i in range(entries):
            self.log.append([])
            self.log[i].append(float(self.channel.recv(10)))
            self.log[i].append(float(self.channel.recv(10)))
            self.log[i].append(self.channel.recv(14))


        self.channel.close()
        print 'Closed connection:', self.details [ 0 ]

        print "The obtained log: "
        print self.log

def main():
    listen = Listen()
    listen.start()
    while True:
        input = raw_input(">>").lower()
        if input in ["start"]:
            if listen.isAlive():
                print "Already started"
            else:
                listen = Listen()
                listen.start()
        if input in ["stop"]:
            if not listen.isAlive():
                print "Already stopped"
            else:
                listen.stop()
        if input in ["exit"]:
            if listen.isAlive():
                listen.stop()
            sys.exit()
        if input in ["status"]:
            print "The server is " + ["not ", ""][listen.isAlive()] + "running"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Eric, what is your question specifically?

Comment: Could you please add the output from `netstat -n --listening` and `ifconfig a` before and after executing your script, and put the output onto e.g. pastebin?

Comment: Okay, so I have set the self.HOST to ''. Here is my netstat and ifconfig before and after: http://pastebin.com/kWwNA6zY

When I run the client script on the server and have it connect to 132.206.31.58, it works fine, but when I run the client script from a different computer, I get:

error: [Errno 10060] A connectino attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: To be honest this suggests your script is perfectly fine and that you instead have a problem with either the "different computer" you're running your client script on or the routing between the "different computer" and the server.  Also, I never through to ask this but why aren't you using SocketServer? http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html

Comment: I've tried contacting the admin, but he hasn't responded. Hopefully a second email will do the trick.

As for SocketServer. I had never heard of it. I might give it a shot though, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `server.bind((self.HOST, self.PORT))`, try:

```
server.bind(('', self.PORT))
```

For IPv4 addresses the empty string represents INADDR_ANY; when receiving a socket bound to this address, your process will receive packets from *all* interfaces (not just the loop-back or the primary Ethernet interface).

Comment: This answer is correct.  However, you can also use "0.0.0.0" as the hostname, which I believe is the same as INADDR_ANY.

Comment: @Asymptote: While this is true, the canonical way to represent INADDR_ANY in Python is by the empty string. [Documentation link](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html).

Comment: I used '' as the host, and it didn't change anything.